# Hide some custom fields in Wordpress backend?

Tags: php, wordpress

Some plugins add custom fields at the post pages (backend) for modification, but some of them I will never modify, they just work. So there are lots of not needed fields between needed fields. Is there a way to **hide** some of this **not needed fields for the backend through the function.php?**

Can anybody help?

Comment: Typically plugin authors will prefix their custom field key with an underscore, like _my_custom_field_key in cases where user editing is not needed. Doing so marks it as 'private' and will prevent it from showing in the post editor custom field metabox. Any chance the ones you're referencing can be changed / user defined?

Comment: I`am not sure what you mean with "Any chance the ones you're referencing can be changed / user defined?"

Comment: Sorry, I meant perhaps you can prefix the ones in question with an underscore ? or are they totally out of your control.

Comment: Ah, ok ;) - unfortunately not, they are out of my control - but good to know that "_" at the beginning will mark it as private.

Comment: Consider posting your solution as a self-answer instead of an update to the question, so that this question can be marked as answered.